# R Post Hoc Tukey HSD Error for GLM

Tags: r

I'm struggling to conduct a post hoc test on a GLM that I run. I have one significant difference but keep getting an error when trying to conduct a TukeyHSD. Can anyone explain to me why this is and how I can correct it?
I am a novice in R... Thanks!

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(sampling_unit) ~ +species_count_rain + species_count_dry   + 
dist_riv + dist_stream, data = GLM1)

Deviance Residuals: 
 Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-15.7321   -3.8064   -0.8604    4.3677   18.3710  

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)        -4.035778   6.108781  -0.661   0.5149  
species_count_rain  0.101275   0.732416   0.138   0.8911  
species_count_dry   2.551763   1.003939   2.542   0.0176 *
dist_riv            0.002783   0.001488   1.871   0.0732 .
dist_stream         0.012681   0.006426   1.974   0.0596 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 55.80858)

Null deviance: 2247.5  on 29  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1395.2  on 25  degrees of freedom
AIC: 212.32

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

> plot(lrfit)
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 

> TukeyHSD(GLM1, species_count_dry, ordered = FALSE, confint.level = 0.95)
Error in UseMethod("TukeyHSD") : 
 no applicable method for 'TukeyHSD' applied to an object of class       "data.frame"
```

Comment: By the looks of it, `GLM1` is your raw data. `TukeyHSD` takes a fitted model as the `x` argument.